# Installing a program before Installing a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Hello I have tried to search for this but I didn't really know how to ask what I'm trying to say, so please forgive my lack of knowledge. I have a very basic program that connects to an Access database via OleDbConnection, for this to work on the computer local machine the user must have [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) installed on the machine. What I'm asking is how can I have this installed or embed the program into this simple application where the user can just install the simple application?

Comment: use an installer, bundle the redistributable and your app together. but telling you which installer to use would be off-topic.

Comment: Create a Visual Studio installation project and add the db engine as a dependency for your application. Can all be in the same solution.